# In live camera object detection how to swich off the camera and leave the boxes

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, computer-vision

first question here. Not waiting an anwer but a bit of direction on how to solve it or documentation to read

I'm learning Tensorflow and I'm working with basic examples of live camera objet detection, and want to input the output in other software (GIS)

Can I alter the final image coming form the camera.OR even turn the image coming from the camera off and leave only the squares and labels

This is the code that draws the rectangles

```
input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.expand_dims(image_np, 0), dtype=tf.float32)
detections, predictions_dict, shapes = detect_fn(input_tensor)

label_id_offset = 1
image_np_with_detections = image_np.copy()

viz_utils.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
      image_np_with_detections,
      detections['detection_boxes'][0].numpy(),
      (detections['detection_classes'][0].numpy() + label_id_offset).astype(int),
      detections['detection_scores'][0].numpy(),
      category_index,
      use_normalized_coordinates=True,
      max_boxes_to_draw=200,
      min_score_thresh=.30,
      agnostic_mode=False)

# Display output
cv2.imshow('object detection', cv2.resize(image_np_with_detections, (800, 600)))
```

The function visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array is part of Tensorflow models/research/object_detection/utils/visualization_utils.py

My first guess was to modify image_np_with_detections to a blank image but it does not work. I have tried to modify directly the visualization utils but it generates an error as is using the image to process the detection.

The other option is to dive into opencv documentation

Any clue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you see how to add something to original image step by step, (like happens in object detection in visualization in your question), but how you can extract the added items only to a result image.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from matplotlib import image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image_np = np.array(Image.open('taulu_seinalla.jpg').convert('RGB'))

#Let's simulate and add some detection info...
image_np_with_detections=image_np.copy()

for i in np.arange(1200,2700):
    image_np_with_detections[300:320,i,:]=[0,255,0]
    image_np_with_detections[1500:1520,i,:]=[0,255,0]

for j in np.arange(300,1500):
    image_np_with_detections[j,1200:1220,:]=[0,255,0]
    image_np_with_detections[j,2700:2720,:]=[0,255,0]

#And now let's create a "boxes leaved" version...
image_difference=image_np_with_detections-image_np
indexes_with_interesting_content=np.where(image_difference[:,:,:]>0)
image_np_boxes_leaved=255*np.ones((len(image_np),len(image_np[0]),3))
image_np_boxes_leaved[indexes_with_interesting_content]=image_np_with_detections[indexes_with_interesting_content]
image_np_boxes_leaved=np.uint8(image_np_boxes_leaved)

#And just for art...
image_np_for_art=255*np.ones((len(image_np),len(image_np[0]),3))
for i in [np.arange(1000,1100),np.arange(2000,2100)]:
    image_np_for_art[500:520,i,:]=[0,0,255]
for i in np.arange(1000,2000):
    y_temp=-0.0005*(i-1500)**2+1500
    y_temp=np.uint(y_temp)
    image_np_for_art[y_temp:(y_temp+20),i,:]=[0,0,255]

image_np_for_art=np.uint8(image_np_for_art)

fig1,((ax1,ax2),(ax3,ax4))=plt.subplots(2,2)
ax1.imshow(image_np)
ax1.set_title('Original')
ax2.imshow(image_np_with_detections)
ax2.set_title('With detections')
ax3.imshow(image_np_boxes_leaved)
ax3.set_title('Boxes leaved')
ax4.imshow(image_np_for_art)
ax4.set_title('Smile!')

plt.show()
```

In practice it looks like somehow that:

[image]